Corda/DLT: Exchange data between different Networks/Different cordapps
Following situation:
We have two compeletly seperate corda applications running on two different networks. Both have been developed by different companies each with own vault, notary, cordapps and so on..
For a new use-case, we would like to transfer some data from one application to the other.
So my question is; Is it possible to exchange data between two corda-nodes on different networks?
Or could we maybe run one node with two different CordApps and exchange the data on the node itself to another CordApp that shares the information with its own network afterwards?
I would appreciate any kind of idea or help how to transer data from one application to the other using Corda. We are able to modify/change both of the applications if it is neccessarry.
Thanks in advance
Florian
